# WordPress auto change post with a specific category at exactly 12:00AM daily

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Can anyone help with a custom hook/code to auto change the post in a category to another category every day at exactly 12:00AM.

I have three categories ( general, special, free )... I have contents with this categories; general & free. So I want any post in the FREE category to change automatically to SPECIAL 12:00AM Daily. So I will have the post in General + SPECIAL category.

Comment: You can use Wordpress Cron ( https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/ ) for this. However, as written in the docs, it will only be triggered on page load - meaning when the first visitor comes after 12:00 AM. The rest works by querying all posts in the 'free' category, looping over them and change the category to 'special'.

Comment: I don't understand.... I have zero knowledge of coding

Comment: I have tried using the post expirator plugin, it does not get the work done

Comment: Then StackOverflow is the wrong platform for you. You unfortunately cannot ask people to write code for you. Even if someone did, you wouldn't know where to put it to make it work (with zero knowledge of coding).

Comment: I know where to put it... Using Code snippet plugin